# Is this possible? Xen on intel host running sparc guest

Tags: solaris, qemu, xen, sparc

I'm wondering if it's possible to run a sparc/solaris guest VM under Xen on an intel based host?

It would seem possible for Qemu to emulate a number of guest architectures (including sparc), therefore it looks doable yet I can't seem to find any reference to anyone who has done this!

Any help/pointers much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.